# "Find in files" shows results in .svn directories

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, flexbuilder

using flex builder 3 and the find in files function alsways searches all files. How can exlude all .svn directories from the search?

Perhaps there is a plugin for that or some way to "always" exlude all matches in these folders.

Thank you!
Regards,
Uwe

Answer (score 1):

There is search filtering built into [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). Or you could try [this plugin](http://weblogs.manas.com.ar/ary/2009/06/19/eclipse-plugin-to-exclude-svn-and-cvs-folders-in-text-search/) (I've not tried it myself)

Comment: The plugin looks good, but flex builder does not have the setting for search engine. Is there a way around that?